# Why aren't my min-width and max-width applying?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a min-width and a max-width applied in my css under media queries to make my web page stick within a certain ideal width. However, my page doesn't seem to be observing my widths. I can't figure out why. Here's my code and what it looks like at large and small dimensions.

```
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-width: 300px;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 4px;
}
.contact-right {
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: left;
}
}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 4px;
}
.contact-right {
    line-height: 0.8em;
    text-align: right;
}
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.0em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    max-width: 992px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 24px;
}
}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    max-width: 992px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}
}
```

As you can see, the width is smaller than the stipulated 300px at one point and larger than 992px at other points.

[image]

[image]

When I change the `margin-left/right` to `auto` I get the following:
[image]

Comment: Considering the devices in your comments, I suppose you should use `max-width` queries instead of `min-width`. i.e `@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {` should be `@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {` and so on for other queries. The reason is, in simple terms, you need to say "if the screen size is less than 320px, then use the following styling".

Comment: The reason I haven't done that is that I don't expect my users to have a screen below 320 pixels, but I can see my users having a screen larger than something like 1200 pixels. I could set another breakpoint at like 10,000 px but that sort of seems ridiculous when I could just do it the other way. I tried your solution and it made no change :(

Answer (score 0):

set margin-left and margin-right properties to auto, to center the elements on webpage.

**CSS**

```
body{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: When I try your solution I get the result that I show in my question above. I've edited it to show you.